# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, codeigniter, array, model

utilizo codeigniter  y quiero recorrer un arreglo con un While pero me da el siguiente error

> -> Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()

```
while ($row=$mate->fetch_assoc()) {
                $mcID['mcID']=$row['mcID'];
                $mcID['mcNombre']=$row['mcNombre'];
            }
```

ese es mi while

Comment: Es preciso ver el código que está antes del `while` para responderte con fundamento. Podría estar ocurriendo que: **A.** Estés intentando llamar el método `fetch_assoc()` sobre el objeto incorrecto. Este método debe llamarse sobre el objeto que devuelve la consulta (**[ver Manual y sus ejemplos](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)**) o **B.** Podría faltarte alguna extensión de MySQLi. Estoy casi seguro que te pasa lo explicado en **A**, para asegurarlo hace falta ver el resto del código.

Answer (score 0):

A mi hace tiempo me pasó algo similar, el asunto estaba en el objeto sobre el que lo aplicaba pues es un poco diferente si estás haciendo una consulta mediante mysqli->query o desde mysqli->prepare, en caso de que sea desde un mysqli->prepare primero debes obtener el resultado de la consulta para posteriormente realizar el fetch_assoc

```
$mate = $prepare->get_result();
while ($row=$mate->fetch_assoc()) {  
  $mcID['mcID']=$row['mcID'];
  $mcID['mcNombre']=$row['mcNombre'];
}
```

No se si sea eso pero te comento mi experiencia con ese error.

### Posible solución final

Revisé la referencia del CodeIgniter y encontré esto, al parecer debes hacer $mate->_fetch_assoc(), te dejo la web: 
http://rmcreative.ru/playground/codeigniter_api/class_c_i___d_b__mysql__result.html#006453d356bca95a5007278abcc92590